# How are modular forms fundamental operations?

Tags: modular-forms

The German mathematician [Martin Eichler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Eichler) once stated that there were five fundamental operations of mathematics: addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and modular forms. This was also mentioned in Simon Singh's book on Fermat's last theorem.

I don't know much about modular forms beyond the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_forms), and am quite confused by this remark. The usual operations seem to be different entities (two numbers input, one number output) than a modular form (one number input, one number output).

Does anyone have some deeper insight into Martin Eichler's assertion?

Comment: It's a **joke** :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6955/modular-forms-eichler-quote